# if request.method == "POST": the pointer is not coming in the if statement can anybody tell?

Tags: django

This code is not working well for the post request in the views file so anybody please try to tell me why the cursor is not going inside the "POST" please find out the problem.

views.py

```
@login_required()
def candidate_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        can = candidate.objects.filter(position = 'President')
        return render(request,'poll/candidate.html',{'can':can})
    else:
        return render(request, 'poll/candidate.html')
```

candidate.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Candidates{% endblock %}
{%block body%}

  <h2>Available Candidates of {{ obj.title }}</h2>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for c in can.candidate_set.all %}
      <!-- <input type="radio" name="{{ c.position}}" value="{{c.id}}" required> <strong>{{c.name}} <a href="{% url 'detail' c.id %}">Detail</a></strong>
     <br> -->
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="id_{{c.id}}" name="{{ c.full_name}}" value="{{c.id}}" class="custom-control-input" required>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_{{c.id}}">{{c.full_name}}</label>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
      <p>No Candidates Available</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" value="VOTE">
  </form>
  <br><p><a href="{% url 'vote' %}">Back to Poll</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

vote.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Positions{% endblock %}
{%block body%}
<form action="" method="POST">
  {%csrf_token%}
  <ul>
    <li><h2><a href="{% url 'candidate_view' %}"> President</a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Vice President </a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Secratary </a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Vice Secratary </a></h2></li>
  </ul>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
    path('register',views.register,name="register"),
    path('login',views.view_login,name="view_login"),
    path('logout',views.view_logout,name="view_logout"),
    path('candidate_view',views.candidate_view,name="candidate_view"),
    path('vote',views.vote,name="vote"),
    path('result',views.result,name="result"),
]
```

Comment: How can you tell the `if` block is not being run? You don't do anything particularly noticeable in the `if`. You make a query and then render the same template (a POST request should ideally end in a redirect) while passing `can` into the context. But then your template really doesn't use that...

Comment: Because else part is executing and if part is not rendering anything

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {%csrf_token%}
  <ul>
    <li><h2><a href="{% url 'candidate_view' %}"> President</a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Vice President </a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Secratary </a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#"> Vice Secratary </a></h2></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

with

```
<form action="{% url 'candidate_view' %}" method="POST">
  {%csrf_token%}
  <label for="President">President</label>
  <input type="radio" id="President" name="position" value="President" />
  <label for="Vice-President">Vice President</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Vice-President" name="position" value="Vice President" />
  ( similarly for secretary and vice secretary )
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also update `view.py` with

```
def candidate_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        can = candidate.objects.filter(position = request.POST.get("position"))
        return render(request,'poll/candidate.html',{'can':can})
    else:
        return render(request, 'poll/vote.html')
```

Comment: Please update your Question with `urls.py` , if doubt persists.

Comment: {% url 'candidate_view' i%} if I using this then the problem is still not resolved

Comment: Yeah I have done that still not resolved.
urlpatterns = [
    path('candidate_view',views.candidate_view,name="candidate_view"),

]

Comment: `{% url 'candidate_view' i%}` what is `i` here ? Try this `href = "{% url 'candidate_view' %}"`

Comment: "{% url 'candidate_view' %}" now I have used this and same thing is happening the candidate_view is opening but that if part of ( if request.method == "POST" ) is not executing while my form method is also POST ??

Comment: Can you please tell me why this is POST request in not getting on?   fine I corrected else part but still POST request is not resolved

Comment: Please update your question with `urls.py` file

Comment: check it now i ve added.

Comment: Can any body suggest what is the problem.

Comment: Have you checked manually ?, the control doesn't go inside the `if block` or the problem is only with rendering contents in template.

Comment: ok just do a final thing, replace `<form action="" method="POST">` with `<form action="{% url 'candidate_view' %}" method="POST">` and you have to pass 'President'  as argument  Accordingly handle the view with parameters

Comment: Here we are not submitting a form, just visiting a link which is a GET request not POST this is where the problem lies. Will update the answer soon, try till then

Comment: No change bro again the same problem persists can I change the template name to candidate_view ??

Comment: Have updated the answer, do that. Then manually check `does the control goes in if block` then let me know

Comment: I have done that and it is working properly bro.

Comment: Glad it worked ! Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you :)